# JQuery - Store BackgroundColor var, animate, then return to var

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-color

I'm trying to store a background color in JQuery so I can animate a background, then return it to it's original color.  The problem is I'm basing the animation on a "a.someclass" being hovered, but the background color property resides on a div class that "a.someclass" link is in.

I'm sure I could restructure my HTML/CSS to accomplish this, but I'm curious as to how I would do it in JQuery.  I think you'll see what I mean when you look at my incorrect JQuery and fiddle.

Insight would be great - http://jsfiddle.net/7FxJC/2/

Many thanks SO

Comment: What're you trying to do in this line: `var ORIGINAL = $this(".configurebox").css('backgroundColor');`? You don't appear to have defined a `$this` variable, you've not called the jQuery object of `$(this)`. Are you using compatibility mode or something?

Comment: That was my attempt at grabbing the current background color.  To be honest, I'm not very good with JQuery, so that was a syntax error and it should've been `$(this)`.  I also realize now that I don't define the background color with `.configurebox` but rather two classes (for the two colors) `.configureboxmodel` and `.configureboxsetup`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can even write $(this('.configureboxmodel')) can I?  and then just write 2 functions for each class?

Comment: What are the two colors? Does the div have anything to do with it? You have a link which is styled to take up the whole area of the div. Can you please explain what effect you would like to see, not how you think you should do it.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being confusing.  The div blocks `.configurebox` have their background colors styled with two different classes, `.configureboxmodel` which background color is `#ccc` and another `.configureboxsetup` which background color is `#0092DD`.  I'm trying to make it so when the link is hovered within those divs, their background color changes to `#8a8a8a`, but then returns to their original color, which varies between the 2 classes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your jsFiddle...  is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/7FxJC/18/

First, the way you were declaring your var ORIGINAL would only allow access to that variable inside of that function (in that case the mouseover function).  Since we needed it to have access beyond that, I used jQuery's .data() method (http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store that  tag's parent's background-color to the element itself, and later recall it when we need it.

I used the .parent() method to grab reference the  tag's parent to grab it's background-color.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery gives a way to store arbitrary "data". You don't write it down on another DOM element by changing someone else's properties.

The following with store a link's background color, animate it's current color to some other color on hover, then return its state on mouseOut. Is this what you had in mid?

```
$("a.configureboxlink").hover(function() {
    var oldColor = $(this).data('oldColor') || $(this).css('background-color');
    $(this).data('oldColor', oldColor)
        .stop().animate({'background-color': 'red'});
}, function() {
    var oldColor = $(this).data('oldColor');
    $(this).stop().animate({'background-color': oldColor});
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FxJC/19/)

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly it.  Sorry about the confusion earlier.  With my limited knowledge I try to approach things in a different way than I probably should and it ends up makings things worse.  Thanks for the clarification.  I'm only voting Justin Lee cuz he needs the rep.  You guys both answered perfectly.